# How to upload a file using Python script to a ExpressJS server?

Tags: python, node.js

I am trying to modify some ExpressJS code (see below) I found online to handle incoming files sent from a Python script and store them in a desired folder...Based on the script I wrote, I suspect that since I am not  passing the uploadDisk.single("image") value, the server is not able to process the POST request (not sure how to accomplish this task). Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks,

P.S. logic works using Postman

***ExpressJS code:***

```
 const express = require("express");
    const bp = require("body-parser");
    const port = 5000;
    const app = express();
    
    const multer = require("multer");
    
    app.use(bp.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bp.json());
    
    app.use(require("morgan")("dev"));
    
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "./"); // here we specify the destination . in this case i specified the current directory
      },
      filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        console.log(file);
        cb(null, file.originalname);// here we specify the file saving name . in this case i specified the original file name
      }
    });
    
    var uploadDisk = multer({ storage: storage });
    
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
     res.send("hello world");
    });
    
    app.post("/fileuploaddisk", uploadDisk.single("image"), (req, res) => {
      console.log(" file disk uploaded");
      res.send("file disk upload success");
    });
    
    app.listen(port, '192.168.1.231', () => {
      console.log("Express server listning on port " + port);
    });
```

***Python code:***

```
 import requests
    
    url = 'http://x.x.x.x:5000/fileuploaddisk'
    
    files = {'file': open('/home/pi/Desktop/test.zip', 'rb')}
    
    
    response = requests.post(url, files=files)
    response.text
    print(response)
```

***Output:***

```
POST /fileuploaddisk 500 647.480 ms - 1232
        MulterError: Unexpected field
            at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\x\Desktop\udcServiceServer\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
            at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hfranyie\Desktop\udcServiceServer\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
            at Busboy.emit (events.js:311:20)
            at Busboy.emit (C:\Users\x\Desktop\udcServiceServer\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
            at PartStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\x\Desktop\udcServiceServer\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
            at PartStream.emit (events.js:311:20)
            at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\x\Desktop\udcServiceServer\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
            at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:311:20)
            at HeaderParser._finish (C:\Users\x\Desktop\udcServiceServer\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8)
            at SBMH.<anonymous> (C:\Users\x\Desktop\udcServiceServer\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:40:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

In ExpressJS code, with the line `uploadDisk.single("image")`, the server is expecting a file named image.

But in the Python code, I couldn't see any name for the file.try `files = {'file': ('image', '/home/pi/Desktop/test.zip', 'rb')}`

Comment: Thanks Mohan, you answer definitely pointed me in the right direction. I had to make a minor tweak though:
files = {'image', open ('/home/pi/Desktop/test.zip', 'rb')}

Comment: Happy that it helped you. An up-vote for the answer will help me

Comment: my apologies sir but unfortunately I only have 11 of reputation. To up-vote your answer, I need to have 15 reputations so the system let me vote :/

I'll do it as soon as reach this milestone.